# I have this error in both Pycharm and VScode. Probably installation?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

My picture won't upload due to server issues but essential the error for just a print command returns as:

Program 'python.exe' failed to  run: The system cannot find the path specified line:1 char:1
+python main.py
+
At line:1 char:1
+python main.py
+
+ Category Info          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ Fully QualifiedErrorId : NativeCammandFailed

I was having an issue with pycharm so I unistalled and reinstalled it, downloaded python 3.10.8, and now I am having this new error.

Comment: Looks like PyCharm doesn't know where to find `python.exe`.  As far as I'm aware, Python does not come bundled with PyCharm; you have to install Python separately.  Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question. I think we can refer to the reply [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/zh-hans/windows/forum/all/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B0%8F%E5%BF%83%E7%94%A8%E4%BA%86/60f63371-74bc-4203-bdf8-37c035a723cc).

Use shortcuts "win+R" and type `PowerShell.exe "Start-Process "cmd" -Verb runas"`.

Copy the following commands, then right-click in the open command prompt window, click "Paste" (or `ctrl+v`), and press **Enter** to execute:

```
CMD /C "ICACLS "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /setowner "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller" & ECHO Y|CACLS "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /S:"D:PAI(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464)(A;;0x1200a9;;;S-1-15-3-1024-3635283841-2530182609-996808640-1887759898-3848208603-3313616867-983405619-2501854204)(A;OICIIO;GXGR;;;S-1-15-3-1024-3635283841-2530182609-996808640-1887759898-3848208603-3313616867-983405619-2501854204)(A;;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;SY)(A;CI;0x1200a9;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;LS)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;NS)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;RC)(XA;;0x1200a9;;;BU;(Exists WIN://SYSAPPID))""
```